# Obtener imágenes de la carpeta media en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estoy tratando de obtener imágenes en Django con `MEDIA_ROOT` y `MEDIA_URL` pero no lo logro conseguir. Les comparto el código implementado hasta el momento:

**setting.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)
```

**listar.html**:

```
{% for i in lis %}
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <td><b>curso</b></td>
                <td><b>{{ i.titulo }} </b></td>

                <td>
                    <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{ i.docfile }}" >
                </td>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

**view.py**:

```
def b(request):
try:

    lis = Document.objects.order_by('titulo')
    return render(request,'listar.html', {'lis':lis})
except:
    pass
return HttpResponse('no se pudo mostrar')
```

Comment: Soy novato  ...espero su comprension y ayuda  ...Gracias de antemano

Comment: Antes de mirar nada en el código Intenta descargar manualmente el archivo para ver si ese es el problema, y no lo estas sirviendo bien.

Comment: no puedo descargar el archivo , como podria mejorar el codigo  ,,, y gracias

Comment: Si no puedes poner en el navegador directamete la url del archivo y descargarlo, tienes un problema con urls.py que no esta sirviendo MEDIA_ROOT, hasta que no arregles eso lo demás es especular.

Comment: verifique lo de la parte de url y llegue a esto pero nada ..

Comment: from almacen.views import a ,b
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$',index,name="index"),
 url(r'^cursos$',mostrarCurso,name="mostrarCurso"),
 url(r'^a$',a,name="a"),
 url(r'^b$',b,name="b"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, es asegurarte de que estas sirviendo los archivos de media, eso se consigue haciendo lo siguiente en tu archivo de `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, }),
)
```

Asi ya sabes que estas sirviendo media, también, asegurate que tengas en tus INSTALLED_APPS en settings la ruta a 'django.contrib.staticfiles'

Ya luego en tu template, al inicio debes importar los staticfiles, y en lugar de buscar tus arhivos de esa forma, hazlo de esta que es mas limpia:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% for i in lis %}
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <td><b>curso</b></td>
                <td><b>{{ i.titulo }} </b></td>

                <td>
                    <img src="{{ i.docfile.url }}" />
                </td>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Donde el atributo `url` retorna la url de la ruta de la imagen, y podrias usar el metodo `_get_path()` desde el servidor para obtener el path completo a la imagen.

Cualquier pregunta, comenta.

Comment: Hola German gracias por comentar ... me sigue dando error al parecer no se realiza correctamente la parte del sirviendo media ....el codigo de url que pusiste me da error  ...por lo que opte  por este pero aun asi no esta sirviendo de manera correcta

Comment: if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)   ....cual es el posible error ...gracias de antemano

Comment: que version de Django estas usando?

Comment: la ultima 1.10 , pero estoy muy seguro de que  realiza la parte de sirviendo media

Comment: Si es asi, puedes acceder a la ruta desde la url y ver que sale... lo que tendrias que hacer es ingresar a http://tudominioOlocalhost:puerto/media/carpetas_donde_guardaste_el_archivo/ y deberias ver la imagen o se descargaria automaticamente, o entra a la shell y con un objeto de Documento busca el atributo de la imagen el FileField y ponle .url, ves a esa url luego

Comment: si tienes razon ...eso si esta funcionando con normalidad ... pero al momento de cargarlo en la plantilla ... hay esta el error

Comment: cargalo con el src a i.docfile.url

Comment: Gracias German  ,por tu tiempo  y tus consejos

Comment: como 3 horas buscando en ingles y no me ha funcionado...y en cinco minutos con tu metodo me ha funcionado..genial !!